# how to fill image Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am using this code to fill the image into Screen.
But It not working for me. Can anyone help?

```
Container(
            height: 200.0,
            width: 340.0,
            child: Image.asset(
              "assets/images/breakfast.jpeg",
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
```

[image: as shown]

Comment: can you show the surrounding Widget of Container() ?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the size values from the `Container` as the image can only take the maximum size provided by the parent widget.

```
   Container(
            child: Image.asset(
              "assets/images/breakfast.jpeg",
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
```

An article for help: https://medium.com/flutteropen/flutter-widgets-03-image-558e2b24059e

Comment: But his image is cutted way before 340 as it looks to me.

Comment: something else is wrong. can you post the image and some more code for your widget?